# sigsuspend vs additional signals delivered during handler execution

Tags: c, signals, posix, language-lawyer

[`sigsuspend`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigsuspend.html) changes the signal mask, suspends execution of the calling thread until it receives a "signal whose action is either to execute a signal-catching function or to terminate the process", and then (if the process is not terminated and the signal handler returns) restores the signal mask to its original state.

The linked page of POSIX.1-2008 doesn't say whether it's possible for *multiple* signals to be delivered within a single call to `sigsuspend`, nor does it say anything about the atomicity of the signal mask changes; i.e. it appears to me that this is a conforming implementation of `sigsuspend`, even though the whole point of `sigsuspend` is that it doesn't have the race condition that this code does:

```
int sigsuspend(const sigset_t *mask)
{
    sigset_t oldmask;
    if (sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, mask, &oldmask)) return -1;
    pause();
    if (sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &oldmask, 0)) return -1;
    return -1;
}
```

The scenario I'm actually worried about is a program that uses `SIGUSR1` to communicate with itself (it's a long story) and I need a way to be sure that the signal handler executes *only once* per internal call to `sigsuspend`, even if other processes on the same system send it signals.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a requirement (in [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) or any other relevant standard) to deliver at most one signal (of any kind) per call to sigsuspend?
2. Is there a requirement (ditto) for sigsuspend to change the signal mask, suspend execution, and restore the signal mask atomically?  That is, without any risk that a signal will be delivered "in between" the three system calls in the hypothetical user-space implementation above?

Since this is fairly abstract, below a test program that I would *like* always to print 1 and exit successfully, but am worried that under some circumstances it might print 2 or 0, hang until the alarm goes off, or crash.  (C11 atomics used out of an overabundance of caution; technically you aren't allowed to *read* a `volatile sig_atomic_t` from a signal handler, only *write* to one.)  It uses SIGUSR1 by default, and SIGRTMIN if you pass `-r` on the command line.

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#include <stdatomic.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#ifndef ATOMIC_INT_LOCK_FREE
#error "This program uses atomic_uint from a signal handler."
#endif

static atomic_uint handler_call_count;
static pid_t self_pid;

static void perror_exit(const char *msg)
{
  perror(msg);
  exit(1);
}

static void handler(int signo)
{
  union sigval dummy;
  dummy.sival_int = 0;

  if (handler_call_count++ == 0)
    if (sigqueue(self_pid, signo, dummy))
      perror_exit("sigqueue");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  sigset_t mask1, mask2;
  struct sigaction sa;
  int signo;
  union sigval dummy;

  if (argc > 1 && !strcmp(argv[1], "-r"))
    signo = SIGRTMIN;
  else
    signo = SIGUSR1;

  sigemptyset(&mask1);
  sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);

  sigaddset(&mask1, signo);
  sigaddset(&sa.sa_mask, signo);

  if (sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask1, &mask2))
    perror_exit("sigprocmask");

  sigdelset(&mask2, SIGALRM);
  sigdelset(&mask2, signo);

  sa.sa_handler = handler;
  sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
  if (sigaction(signo, &sa, 0))
    perror_exit("sigaction");

  self_pid = getpid();
  dummy.sival_int = 0;
  if (sigqueue(self_pid, signo, dummy))
    perror_exit("sigqueue");

  alarm(5);
  sigsuspend(&mask2);
  alarm(0);

  printf("%u\n", atomic_load(&handler_call_count));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The Linux implementation saves the old set in per-thread task structure, and atomically restores the set when the first signal is delivered or acted upon. The details are complicated, but it basically boils down to the signal mask being restored for the thread, always before [`kernel/signal.c:next_signal()`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/signal.c) is called to see if there is another pending signal. Also, all of this is *per-thread* in Linux; I'm not sure if pthreads implementation of signal masks is raceless in multithreaded programs.

Comment: @NominalAnimal: But which "old" signal mask is restored? Is it the set before or after `sigsuspend()` that is restored after the handler's (sigaction.sa_mask) mask is set for it's execution? This would effect whether the it possible to guarantee one execution of the handler in the OP's circumstance - for Linux anyway.

Comment: @S.Pinkus: The set before the call. `sigsuspend()` (or `rt_sigsuspend()`) syscall causes the current set (the set before the call) to be saved into `current->saved_sigmask` in [`kernel/signal.c:sigsuspend()`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/signal.c) before any signal checks. The `set_restore_sigmask()` only marks that to be restored. The saved sigmask is restored when returning from the first signal delivery, per comment in [`kernel/signal.c:signal_delivered()`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/signal.c).

Comment: @zwol: Could you use a semaphore to keep count of the number of times `SIGUSR1` was delivered -- `sem_post(&signal_sem)` being async-signal-safe in POSIX.1-2008, and thus okay to use in a signal handler; basically just that in the body of the signal handler -- and use `!sem_trywait(&signal_sem)` to see if an action should be taken for the signal? You could even use `for (; !sem_trywait(&signal_sem);) ;` to consume the extra signal deliveries. All this assumes the signal is normally blocked, of course.

Comment: About the _reading-`sig_atomic_t`-is-illegal_ part: [In 2008 ISO ruled that](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/SIG31-C.+Do+not+access+shared+objects+in+signal+handlers) in no known implementations would reading them be an error, and that the intent had been to permit both read and write.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## 1) Is there a requirement for handling at most one signal?

**No.** In fact, the opposite is *recommended*. POSIX 2008's *Volume 4: Rationale, §B.2.4.1 Signal Generation and Delivery* states:

> When there are multiple pending signals that are not blocked, implementations should arrange for the delivery of all signals at once, if possible. Some implementations stack calls to all pending signal-catching routines, making it appear that each signal-catcher was interrupted by the next signal. In this case, the implementation should ensure that this stacking of signals does not violate the semantics of the signal masks established by `sigaction()`. Other implementations process at most one signal when the operating system is entered, with remaining signals saved for later delivery. Although this practice is widespread, this behavior is neither standardized nor endorsed. In either case, implementations should attempt to deliver signals associated with the current state of the process (for example, `SIGFPE`) before other signals, if possible.

Moreover, it **is** possible for multiple signals with the same signal number to be queued simultaneously. POSIX 2008 *Volume 2: System Interfaces, §2.4.1 Signal Generation and Delivery* states

> If a subsequent occurrence of a pending signal is generated, it is implementation-defined as to whether the signal is delivered or accepted more than once in circumstances other than those in which queuing is required. The order in which multiple, simultaneously pending signals outside the range SIGRTMIN to SIGRTMAX are delivered to or accepted by a process is unspecified.

This also applies to real-time signals. POSIX 2008 *Volume 2: System Interfaces, §2.4.2 Realtime Signal Generation and Delivery* states

> [...] Multiple occurrences of signals so generated are queued in FIFO order. [...]
>
> If, when a pending signal is delivered, there are additional signals queued to that signal number, the signal shall remain pending. Otherwise, the pending indication shall be reset.

## 2) Is there a requirement for atomicity?

**Legitimately Debatable.** It was probably intended, but it's not actually spelled out normatively. There are good arguments in favour and against:

### The case *for* atomicity:

POSIX 2008 does strongly imply atomicity in *Volume 2: System Interfaces, §3 `pause()`*:

> #### APPLICATION USAGE
>
> Many common uses of `pause()` have timing windows. The scenario involves checking a condition related to a signal and, if the signal has not occurred, calling `pause()`. When the signal occurs between the check and the call to `pause()`, the process often blocks indefinitely. The `sigprocmask()` and `sigsuspend()` functions can be used to avoid this type of problem.

A similar strong implication appears under the **RATIONALE** heading for `sleep()`. Additionally, the word **can** is defined in POSIX 2008 *Volume 1: Base Definitions, §1.5 Terminology`* as:

> For the purposes of POSIX.1-2008, the following terminology definitions apply:
>
> **can**
>
> Describes a permissible optional feature or behavior available to the user or application. The feature or behavior is mandatory for an implementation that conforms to POSIX.1-2008. An application can rely on the existence of the feature or behavior.

And POSIX 2008's *Volume 4: Rationale, §A.1.5 Terminology* states:

> **may**
>
> The use of *may* has been limited as much as possible, due both to confusion stemming from its ordinary English meaning and to objections regarding the desirability of having as few options as possible and those as clearly specified as possible.
>
> The usage of *can* and *may* were selected to contrast optional application behavior (can) against optional implementation behavior (may).

That is to say, `pause()`'s **APPLICATION USAGE** heading states that an application is not obliged to call `sigsuspend()` to avoid timing problems, but should it choose to, then POSIX.1-2008-conformant implementations of `sigsuspend()` are required to avoid said timing-window problems (e.g. be atomic, with the help of the kernel).

If `sigsuspend()` were not atomic, then

- The statement that an application can avoid timing window problems by using `sigsuspend()` is false, and thus all versions of the POSIX.1 standard since the first one in 1988 are internally inconsistent.
- `sigsuspend()` would be useless, since it would serve no purpose beyond `pause()`. One would then have to ask why would POSIX.1 include both since the very first version, along with a false recommendation to use `sigsuspend()` in preference to `pause()`.

### The case *against* atomicity:

POSIX 2008 *Volume 2: System Interfaces, §1.2 Format of Entries* states:

> [...]
>
> **APPLICATION USAGE**
>
> This section is informative.
>
> This section gives warnings and advice to application developers about the entry. In the event of conflict between warnings and advice and a normative part of this volume of POSIX.1-2008, the normative material is to be taken as correct.
>
> **RATIONALE**
>
> This section is informative.
>
> This section contains historical information concerning the contents of this volume of POSIX.1-2008 and why features were included or discarded by the standard developers.
>
> [...]

This means that these sections are *informative*, not *normative*, and only *normative* sections can directly impose requirements on the implementor. However, they can help in *interpreting* the Standard, and the statement that "*The `sigprocmask()` and `sigsuspend()` functions can be used to avoid this type of problem*" does not conflict with any normative portion of the Standard.

### Neutral case

POSIX 2008's *Volume 4: Rationale, §A.1.5 Terminology* states:

> **implementation-defined**
>
> This definition is analogous to that of the ISO C standard and, together with ‘‘undefined’’ and ‘‘unspecified’’, provides a range of specification of freedom allowed to the interface implementor.
>
> [...]
>
> **unspecified**
>
> See implementation-defined.
>
> [...]
>
> In many places POSIX.1-2008 is silent about the behavior of some possible construct. For example, a variable may be defined for a specified range of values and behaviors are described for those values; nothing is said about what happens if the variable has any other value. That kind of silence can imply an error in the standard, but it may also imply that the standard was intentionally silent and that any behavior is permitted. There is a natural tendency to infer that if the standard is silent, a behavior is prohibited. That is not the intent. Silence is intended to be equivalent to the term ‘‘unspecified’’.

The ISO C Standard (presently, C11) defines *"implementation-defined behaviour"* as behaviour where the implementation can choose, but must document its choice.

The absence of any normative statement on the atomicity of `sigsuspend()` is perhaps either an error or equivalent to an explicit statement that it is implementation-defined behaviour.

- The application notes and rationale in `pause()` and `sleep()` suggest that it is an error in the Standard.
- But conversely, an implicit normative statement that `sigsuspend()`'s atomicity is implementation-defined takes precedence over an informative statement to the contrary.

### Implementations

So can we inspire ourselves from in-the-wild implementations? Perhaps. I know of no implementations that don't implement it atomically:

- **Linux** kernels implement `sigsuspend()` atomically.
- **BSD** kernels implement `sigsuspend()` atomically.

Comment: So, 1) says that using e.g. `sigfillset(&act.sa_mask)` when installing a signal handler using `sigaction(signum, &act, ...)` stops the signal handler from being interrupted (other than by non-catchable signals like `KILL` and `STOP`, which don't matter here anyway). However, 2) does not say that only one signal should be delivered sequentially before returning to the original thread; it only says that `sigsuspend()` et al. won't *miss* a signal, or have a race window. I am not disagreeing with you; I am just saying 2) is very weak, and we should find something stronger.

Comment: @NominalAnimal I've never claimed that that was what 1) and 2) said. I think 1) is a recommendation for an implementation to invoke multiple handlers per interruption, effectively as if each handler was interrupted on completion by the next. 2) clearly states that `sigsuspend()` is not vulnerable to timing problems. To have at-most-one signal handled per call to `sigsuspend()`, I think you'll have to mask all signals in the handler, forcing the remaining pending signals to wait some more.

Comment: No, you didn't; only I did. First point has *two* implementation possibilities: actual interruption of a signal handler (say, by chaining the signal handlers in userspace), or sequentially firing the signal handlers (by returning to the kernel in between, but without yielding any CPU time to the thread otherwise). Signal masking blocks the former. Realtime signals are queued, and standard POSIX signals *may* be, so I'm worried about the case where an implementation queues the `SIGUSR1` (that OP is using), and sequentially executes the handler in the same thread.

Comment: The Linux kernel (uses the latter, above, and) handles this ambiquity by reverting to the original signal mask when the signal is delivered. It does try to deliver multiple signals, and does check the set of pending signals after the handler returns, but at that point the original mask is already in effect, so only one userspace handler will be executed for the thread. What I don't see in your answer, yet, is a passage from POSIX.1-2008 that says (I'd be happy with *implies*) that if a signal is queued twice for a process or the thread, only one is delivered per `sigsuspend()` call.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Yep, found it. It states black and white that this is implementation-dependent. There is **not** a mandate to deliver only once per signal number.

Comment: Agreed. I do believe that your answer (per the latest edit) is conclusive now. (My words:) POSIX does not guarantee that the signal handler for `SIGUSR1` only gets executed once per call to `sigsuspend()`.

Comment: But if POSIX guarantees the signal mask is restored after the execution of the handler, and before the next pending signal is considered (I assume it does - just seems like the only correct behavior), and that signal mask is the ~ "before sigsuspend()" signal mask, then it's *possible* to guarantee only one handle-able signal is processed, given you block all signals in your "before sigsuspend()" signal mask. Right? Although, I can't find anything in POSIX standards that specifies that the signal mask is the "before sigsuspend()" one.

Comment: @S.Pinkus It doesn't; The wording not only permits but recommends that handlers effectively interrupt each other sequentially. The sigsuspend() only needs to return after at least one handler(s) have run, and must restore the before-sigsuspend() mask.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist It doesn't to which part? Guarantee the signal mask is restored or restore the "before sigsuspend()" signal mask? Also I dont quite follow "wording .. recommends that handlers effectively interrupt each other sequentially". I agree >1 handler can and should be invoked before control is returned to the main, but whether they actually **can** is still subject to the mask. So it depends what signal mask exists before and after handler execution.

Comment: @S.Pinkus It's the "before next pending signal" part I objected to. 1+ handlers can and should be invoked with the post-sigsuspend() mask (enabling a userland to iterate through e.g. a linked list of pending signals to invoke without having to bounce between user and kernel modes), then when the implementation feels like it (e.g. once no more unblocked pending signals are left) it atomically switches back to pre-sigsuspend() mask and returns from sigsuspend().

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist Yeah, that is what I thought should happen as well. But I can't find anything in POSIX that says one way or the other. In Linux as \@NominalAnimal claims, and my testing just now suggests, they've implemented the alternative. I think the conclusion has to be that because the standard is ambiguous, one can't rely on one or the other implementation.

Comment: @S.Pinkus But doesn't §B.2.4.1 make it clear that as-if-stacked-handler execution means you don't return from sigsuspend() until the stack of interruptions unwinds? _"When there are multiple pending signals that are not blocked, implementations should arrange for the delivery of all signals at once, if possible. Some implementations stack calls to all pending signal-catching routines, making it appear that each signal-catcher was interrupted by the next signal."_

Comment: "When there are multiple pending signals that are **not blocked** ...". That is exactly what I my argument hinges on: You can/cannot ensure that all signals are blocked depending on what mask it is that's restored - the before or after mask. Also, I'm not sure what you are quoting. Can you please update your answer with links?

Comment: @S.Pinkus While the thread is `sigsuspend()`'ed, the signals being handled are not blocked. POSIX permits multiple signals to be delivered "all at once".  When a thread receives an unblocked signal that is to be handled, the signal number is blocked until the handler returns. Now, the implementation has handled at least one signal, and has a choice to make: Either continue handling signals from the queue (e.g. by unblocking the just-handled signal and instantly rehandling it) or atomically return from `sigsuspend()` and restore the previous mask. The §B.2.4.1 quote is in my answer already.

Comment: I'm satisfied with this as an answer to question 1, but for 2 it's not quite there yet.  The text you've quoted says to me that the POSIX committee _intended_ `sigsuspend` to be race-free, but because it appears in an APPLICATION USAGE section for a different function entirely, I am not certain it imposes a binding requirement on implementations.  I reread both function specifications and the "Conformance" page and I'm none the wiser.

Comment: @zwol I agree that that is an extremely bizarre place and manner for expressing a requirement. But the wording doesn't permit me to conclude anything other than that `sigsuspend()` **must** have atomicity, for if it did not then a) the standard makes a false recommendation, thus is internally inconsistent and b) the function serves no purpose beyond pause().

Comment: @zwol Well, I revisited the topic and I've come to the conclusion that 2) is legitimately debatable; See my numerous additional quotes. This matter should be brought up to the attention of the Austin Group.

Answer (score 6):

This is not an answer, but an exploratory program. I'm hoping that a kind macOS and/or *BSD user might test it on their machines, and report their results.

---

Just out of interest, I wrote a crude program to assess how often more than one signal is delivered per call to `sigsuspend()`.

The idea in the following program is to let the user specify the signal on the command line. The process will fork a child process.

The child process blocks that signal, then installs a signal handler that atomically (using GCC built-ins) increments a counter. It will then enter into a loop, where it stops itself (via `raise(SIGSTOP)`). The parent process will detect this, and send a cluster of the signals, then `SIGCONT`. When the child process wakes up, it calls `sigsuspend()` until no more signals are pending. For each `sigsuspend()` call, the number of delivered signals is counted. After there are no more signals pending, the child stops itself again.

The parent sends half the (copies of the) signal using `kill()`, the rest using `sigqueue()` with a varying payload.

This is an utter hack, may not at all follow the POSIX.1 standard, and probably contains lots of bugs. (If you notice any, please let me know in a comment, so I can fix it.)

```
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

#ifndef   CLUSTER
#define   CLUSTER 8
#endif

#ifndef   INTERVAL
#define   INTERVAL 100000
#endif

static const struct {
    const int  number;
    const char name[8];
} signal_list[] = {
    { SIGHUP,     "HUP"     },
    { SIGINT,     "INT"     },
    { SIGQUIT,    "QUIT"    },
    { SIGILL,     "ILL"     },
    { SIGABRT,    "ABRT"    },
    { SIGFPE,     "FPE"     },
    { SIGSEGV,    "SEGV"    },
    { SIGPIPE,    "PIPE"    },
    { SIGALRM,    "ALRM"    },
    { SIGTERM,    "TERM"    },
    { SIGUSR1,    "USR1"    },
    { SIGUSR2,    "USR2"    },
    { SIGTSTP,    "TSTP"    },
    { SIGTTIN,    "TTIN"    },
    { SIGTTOU,    "TTOU"    },
    { SIGBUS,     "BUS"     },
    { SIGPOLL,    "POLL"    },
    { SIGPROF,    "PROF"    },
    { SIGSYS,     "SYS"     },
    { SIGTRAP,    "TRAP"    },
    { SIGURG,     "URG"     },
    { SIGVTALRM,  "VTALRM"  },
    { SIGXCPU,    "XCPU"    },
    { SIGXFSZ,    "XFSZ"    },
    { SIGIO,      "IO"      },
    { SIGPWR,     "PWR"     },
    { SIGWINCH,   "WINCH"   },
    { -1,         ""        }
};


static volatile sig_atomic_t done = 0;

static void handle_done(int signum)
{
    done = 1;
}

static int install_done(int signum)
{
    struct sigaction act;

    memset(&act, 0, sizeof act);
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    act.sa_handler = handle_done;
    act.sa_flags = 0;
    if (sigaction(signum, &act, NULL) == -1)
        return errno;

    return 0;
}

static unsigned long counter = 0UL;
static void          increment_counter(void)     { __atomic_add_fetch(&counter, 1UL, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST); }
static unsigned long get_and_clear_counter(void) { return __atomic_fetch_and(&counter, 0UL, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST); }

static void handle_counter(int signum)
{
    increment_counter();
}

static int install_counter(int signum)
{
    struct sigaction  act;

    memset(&act, 0, sizeof act);
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    sigaddset(&act.sa_mask, signum);
    act.sa_handler = handle_counter;
    act.sa_flags = 0;
    if (sigaction(signum, &act, NULL) == -1)
        return errno;

    return 0;
}

int child_process(int signum)
{
    sigset_t      signals, no_signals, pending;
    unsigned long count, corrects, incorrects, cluster, noncluster, clustercount, nonclustercount;
    int           result, exitcode;

    sigemptyset(&no_signals);
    sigemptyset(&signals);
    sigaddset(&signals, signum);

    if (sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &signals, NULL) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Child: Cannot block the signal: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (install_done(SIGINT) ||
        install_done(SIGHUP) ||
        install_done(SIGTERM) ||
        install_counter(signum)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Child: Cannot install signal handlers: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Ready to wait for signals to become pending. */
    exitcode = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    corrects = 0UL;         incorrects = 0UL;
    cluster = 0UL;          clustercount = 0UL;
    noncluster = CLUSTER;   nonclustercount = 0UL;

    raise(SIGSTOP);

    while (1) {

        if (done)
            return exitcode;

        sigemptyset(&pending);
        if (sigpending(&pending) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Child: Sigpending failed: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        if (!sigismember(&pending, signum)) {
            if (cluster != CLUSTER) {
                if (cluster != noncluster) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Child: Signals are delivered in clusters of %lu signals; expected %d.\n", cluster, CLUSTER);
                    noncluster = cluster;
                }
                nonclustercount++;
            } else
                clustercount++;
            if ((clustercount + nonclustercount) % INTERVAL == 0UL) {

                if (incorrects > 0UL)
                    printf("Child: %lu times out of %lu times only one signal is delivered per sigsuspend() call.\n", corrects, corrects + incorrects);
                else
                    printf("Child: All %lu times sigsuspend() was called, only one signal was delivered.\n", corrects);

                if (clustercount > 0UL && nonclustercount > 0UL)
                    printf("Child: In %lu of %lu sets of signals, all %d copies of the signal were delivered.\n", clustercount, clustercount + nonclustercount, CLUSTER);
                else
                if (clustercount > 0UL)
                    printf("Child: In all %lu sets of signals, all %d copies of the signal were delivered.\n", clustercount, CLUSTER);

                fflush(stdout);
            }
            cluster = 0UL;
            raise(SIGSTOP);
        }

        if (done)
            return exitcode;

        result = sigsuspend(&no_signals);
        if (result != -1 || errno != EINTR) {
            printf("Child: sigsuspend() returned %d, expected -1 with errno == EINTR!\n", result);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        if (done)
            return exitcode;

        count = get_and_clear_counter();
        cluster += count;
        if (count != 1UL) {
            printf("Child: Received %lu signals on one sigsuspend() call!\n", count);
            fflush(stdout);
            exitcode = EXIT_FAILURE;
            ++incorrects;
        } else
            ++corrects;
    }
}

int parse_signum(const char *name)
{
    unsigned int u;
    int          i;
    char         c;

    if (!name || !*name) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return -1;
    }

    if (name[0] == 'S' &&
        name[1] == 'I' &&
        name[2] == 'G' &&
        name[3] != '\0')
        for (i = 0; signal_list[i].number >= 0; i++)
            if (!strcmp(name + 3, signal_list[i].name))        
                return signal_list[i].number;

    for (i = 0; signal_list[i].number >= 0; i++)
        if (!strcmp(name, signal_list[i].name))        
            return signal_list[i].number;

    if ((sscanf(name, " SIGRT%u %c", &u, &c) == 1 ||
         sscanf(name, " RT%u %c", &u, &c) == 1 ||
         sscanf(name, " SIGRTMIN+%u %c", &u, &c) == 1 ||
         sscanf(name, " RTMIN+%u %c", &u, &c) == 1) &&
         u <= (unsigned int)(SIGRTMAX - SIGRTMIN))
        return SIGRTMIN + u;

    if ((sscanf(name, " SIGRTMAX-%u %c", &u, &c) == 1 ||
         sscanf(name, " RTMAX-%u %c", &u, &c) == 1) &&
         u <= (unsigned int)(SIGRTMAX - SIGRTMIN))
        return SIGRTMAX - u;

    errno = EINVAL;
    return -1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t child, p;
    int   signum, i, status;

    if (argc != 2 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [ -h | --help ]\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s [ -l | --list ]\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s SIGNAL\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "This program uses a stopped child process to see if\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "a single call to sigsuspend() can cause more than\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "one SIGNAL to be delivered.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    if (!strcmp(argv[1], "-l") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--list")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "List of known standard POSIX signals:\n");
        for (i = 0; signal_list[i].number >= 0; i++)
            fprintf(stderr, "\tSIG%-7s (%d)\n", signal_list[i].name, signal_list[i].number);
        fprintf(stderr, "POSIX realtime signals can be referred to as\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "\tSIGRTMIN+0      or SIGRTMAX-%d\n", SIGRTMAX-SIGRTMIN);
        fprintf(stderr, "\t                to\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "\tSIGRTMIN+%d     or SIGRTMAX-0\n", SIGRTMAX-SIGRTMIN);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    if (install_done(SIGINT) ||
        install_done(SIGHUP) ||
        install_done(SIGTERM)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Parent: Cannot install signal handlers: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    signum = parse_signum(argv[1]);
    if (signum < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Unknown signal.\n", argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (signum >= SIGRTMIN && signum <= SIGRTMAX)
        fprintf(stderr, "Using POSIX realtime signal number %d (SIGRTMIN%+d)\n", signum, signum-SIGRTMIN);
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "Using standard POSIX signal number %d.\n", signum);

    child = fork();
    if (child == (pid_t)-1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot fork a child process: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } else
    if (!child)
        return child_process(signum);

    /* Parent process. */
    while (!done) {

        /* Wait for child to become stopped or continued. */
        while (!done) {

            do {
                p = waitpid(child, &status, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);
            } while (!done && p == (pid_t)-1 && errno == EINTR);
            if (done)
                break;

            if (p == (pid_t)-1) {
                if (errno == EINTR)
                    continue;
                fprintf(stderr, "Parent: Child process vanished: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            } else
            if (p != child)
                continue;

            if (WIFSTOPPED(status) || WIFCONTINUED(status))
                break;

            if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
                if (WEXITSTATUS(status))
                    fprintf(stderr, "Parent: Child exited with exit status %d.\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
                else
                    fprintf(stderr, "Parent: Child exited successfully.\n");
            } else
            if (WIFSIGNALED(status))
                fprintf(stderr, "Parent: Child died from signal %d.\n", WTERMSIG(status));
            else
                fprintf(stderr, "Parent: Lost child process.\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        if (done)
            break;

        if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {

            /* Send child a total of CLUSTER signals.
               Half of them using sigqueue(), half via kill().
            */
            i = 0;
            while (i < CLUSTER) {
                union sigval sv;
                sv.sival_int = ++i;
                sigqueue(child, signum, sv);
                if (i++ < CLUSTER)
                    kill(child, signum);
            }

            /* Wake child up. */
            kill(child, SIGCONT);
        }

    }

    /* Tell the child process to terminate. */
    kill(child, SIGCONT);
    kill(child, signum);
    kill(child, SIGTERM);

    while (1) {
        p = waitpid(child, &status, 0);
        if (p == (pid_t)-1) {
            if (errno == EINTR)
                continue;
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        if (p == child)
            return status; /* HACK to return the child process status as-is */
    }
}
```

Saving the above as e.g. `hack.c`, and compiling and running it using

```
gcc -Wall -O2 hack.c -o hack
./hack SIGUSR1
```

provides the output for the case the OP is worried about. In Linux on x86-64 architecture (kernel 4.4.0, GCC 5.4.0) it outputs something like

```
Using standard POSIX signal number 10.
Child: Signals are delivered in clusters of 1 signals; expected 8.
Child: All 100000 times sigsuspend() was called, only one signal was delivered.
Child: All 200000 times sigsuspend() was called, only one signal was delivered.
Child: All 300000 times sigsuspend() was called, only one signal was delivered.
Child: All 400000 times sigsuspend() was called, only one signal was delivered.
```

The above output shows that all 400,000 times `sigsuspend()` was called, only one signal was delivered. (However, only one instance of the signal was delivered, even if the parent sent it 8 times: four with different `sigqueue()` payloads, four with kill()`.)

As I mentioned in a comment, based on the Linux kernel sources, I do believe the Linux kernel delivers only one signal per `sigsuspend()` call, if the signal is blocked before (and thus after) the `sigsuspend()` call. The above output supports that belief.

Running the same with a realtime signal, say `./hack SIGRTMIN+0`, outputs something like

```
Using POSIX realtime signal number 34 (SIGRTMIN+0)
Child: All 800000 times sigsuspend() was called, only one signal was delivered.
Child: In all 100000 sets of signals, all 8 copies of the signal were delivered.
Child: All 1600000 times sigsuspend() was called, only one signal was delivered.
Child: In all 200000 sets of signals, all 8 copies of the signal were delivered.
Child: All 2400000 times sigsuspend() was called, only one signal was delivered.
Child: In all 300000 sets of signals, all 8 copies of the signal were delivered.
Child: All 3200000 times sigsuspend() was called, only one signal was delivered.
Child: In all 400000 sets of signals, all 8 copies of the signal were delivered.
```

which shows that on this run, every single instance of the signal was delivered, exactly once per `sigsuspend()` call.

This program cannot provide any sort of proof that a system works as the OP hopes (or that Linux works how I believe it works based on the kernel sources). It can only be used to disprove it (and on Linux, my belief). If there is a system that reports

```
Child: Received # signals on one sigsuspend() call!
```

with # being 2 or greater, then we know that on that system, more than one (copy of the) signal is delivered per sigsuspend() call.

(The case of # being 0 should only occur if the signal chosen is SIGINT, SIGHUP, or SIGTERM, these also being caught, so that the user can stop the program.)

It is of course not guaranteed that even if run on such a system, this program will manage to stumble upon the multiple-delivery case.

However, having the child process stop, get multiple (copies of a) signal, and then continued, would be the optimal point for a system to deliver more than one (copy of the) signal per sigsuspend() call. If it does not do that in this case, what would be the case where it would?

Comment: Very cool work, and it can be useful to show positives. If you can identify OSes that were certified POSIX-compliant, and they exhibit a behaviour (like executing a handler multiple times for a single call to `sigsuspend()`), then we know that this behaviour is POSIX-compliant (in theory at least).

Comment: FreeBSD's implementation is here: [`kern_sigsuspend()`](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/kern/kern_sig.c#L1485) and [`postsig()`](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/kern/kern_sig.c?im=bigexcerpts#L2911) The comments are useful. Seems to suggest multiple signals handled before restoring control to user.

Answer (score 3):

This is the outline of the `sem_post()`/`sem_wait()` workaround I mentioned in a comment to the original question.

This assumes `SIGUSR1` is normally blocked; only un-blocked for the duration of the `sigsuspend()` call.

First, the signal handler is replaced with a simple signal handler that just posts a dedicated semaphore:

```
sem_t  sigusr1_semaphore;

void sigusr1_handler(int signum)
{
    sem_post(&sigusr1_semaphore);
}

void sigusr1_work(void)
{
    /* Whatever the original handler did */
}

int install_sigusr1_handler(void)
{
    struct sigaction  act;

    sem_init(&sigusr1_semaphore, 0, 0);

    memset(&act, 0, sizeof act);
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    sigaddset(&act.sa_mask, SIGUSR1);
    act.sa_handler = sigusr1_handler;
    act.sa_flags = 0;

    if (sigaction(SIGUSR1, &act, NULL) == -1)
        return errno; /* Failed */   

    return 0;
}
```

Each call to `sigsuspend()` that unblocks the above signal handler will have this bit of code added immediately after it:

```
    if (!sem_trywait(&sigusr1_semaphore)) {
        sigusr1_work();
        while (!sem_trywait(&sigusr1_semaphore));
    }
```

Technically, `sigsuspend()` returns before the actual work is done. However, since the work is done in the same thread, there should be no real difference if the work is done before the statement following the `sigsuspend()` instead. After all, `sigsuspend()` only affects the threads signal mask, so the ordering (between the work and return from `sigsuspend()`) is purely internal to the thread.

(Edited to note that OP, zwol, pointed out that there are cases where it does matter. In the OP's case, the signal handler uses an alternate stack, which means the work cannot really be moved to the normal program flow.)

You could obviously achieve the same using a per-thread atomic variable.

(At this point in time, not all C compilers support atomic operations in portable ways, but all POSIXy systems should support semaphores. I would personally use atomic ops, but wrapped in helper functions, to make them easy to port if necessary.)

Comment: For reasons too tedious to get into here, the actual work _has_ to be done inside the signal handler proper; it can't be deferred to normal control flow.  I'm probably going to go with a simple "the work has already been done" flag, set by the handler on its first invocation, and cleared by the outer loop.

Comment: (Since I now notice that you made an argument that it shouldn't matter whether the work is done inside or outside the signal handler, a gesture in the general direction of why it does matter: signal stacks.)

Comment: @zwol: Ouch. Oww. Indeed, there are a few scenarios where it matters, and I ignored those, as they are quite painful; I didn't even think of the case where the signal handler runs on an alternate stack... (My sympathies. I once worked on a horrible Perl project almost twenty years ago, and still have an irrational aversion to Perl as a result. I hope your *mettle* is stronger than mine. :) Anyway, I shall leave this suggestion be, in the wan hope it might be of help to someone else.